# iOS programatically taking a screen shot messes up the image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-graphics, quartz-core

I want to take a screen shot every time user holds the screen for one second and then open up an email window to let the user send the image. But I have a strange problem; the image gets messed up if a gradient image is present (`UIImage` which has a PNG gradient loaded in it - will explain).

So I created a `UILongPressGestureRecgnizer`, set it's `minimumPressDuration` to `1.0f` and added it to the main view as the gesture recognizer: `[self.view addGestureRecognizer:myRecognizer]`. The recognizer calls a method, lets say `shareClicked`. In which I want to capture the current screen and pop up the email composer with that image in it. Here is how I do it:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailComposer setSubject:@"Share feature"];
    [mailComposer setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Im sharing this with you cause its cool."] isHTML:NO];
    [mailComposer addAttachmentData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"image"];

    [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

BUT, there is a problem. There is a table view present on the main view and in the third cell there is a gradient I mentioned earlier. Im not sure how to explain it but its something like this:

[image]

As visible on the image there is a gradient on the top and there is another one  a bit lower. The top one gets rendered normally while the second one causes a strange problem. The gradient is not actually blue but its white and goes to transparent. Here is an image of the gradient on black surface:
[image]

Here is a screen shot from the simulator how it should look:

[image]

And finally here is how it gets rendered and displayed in the mail composer:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? What is the problem? Its not simulator's fault cause it's the same on mobile device as well. Its iOS7 if that makes any difference.

Just to be clear the top gradient is the same but radial and its rendered perfectly. Both gradients are subviews to tableview's cell. How to fix it? Hopefully we find a solution as I did spend some time to "craft" this question :)

Comment: You can pass `0` to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` to have it use the main screen's scale.

Comment: How are you doing the gradient? Are you drawing that in code using CGGradient/CGShading, or loading an image that you made separately? You mention a PNG file; is that file a valid standard PNG, or the sort of crushed PNG you need to be using? Check your “Compress PNG images” (or whatever it's called) build setting and make sure it's turned on.

Comment: Also, does your view override `drawRect:`? If so, please edit your question to include the implementation. If not, is its layer a custom layer, a layer with a delegate, or a plain layer whose `contents` are set elsewhere? Either way, please edit your question to include the code that either draws into the layer's context or sets the layer's `contents`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to the recomended solution https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1703/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010193 as UIGetScreenImage is no more allowed

Comment: This one is no good, it causes that ugly white thing as shown above. How to fix it?